# Groups and subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

if $G$ is a finite group.
$H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ 
and $|H|=18$, $|K|=25$
than why the  intersection of $H$ and $K$ is only the unit element and can't include more elements?

Comment: What do you know about the intersection of two subgroups? What do you know about the order of a subgroup?

Answer (score 3):

The intersection of any two subgroups of $G$ is again a subgroup of $G$. By lagrange's theorem $|H\cap K|| |H|,|K|$ . What is $\gcd(|H|,|K)$

Comment: I guess it something with Lagrange but why if the gcd=1 we get this?

Comment: oh thank you now I understand:)!

Comment: $|H\cap K|$ is common divisor of $18,25$. The only common divisor of $18,25$ is $1$

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is a group and $H,K$ be two subgroups of it, as @Amr noted, you can prove that $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing in both $H$ and $K$. So $$H\cap K\subseteq H~~\text{and}~~H\cap K\subseteq K$$ so according to Lagrange theorem since $H$ and $K$ are both finite so the order of $H\cap K$,say $t$, is finite and divides $|H|$ and $|K|$. Now find the number that divides $25$ and $18$ simultaneously. It is just $t=1$.

Comment: Very neat and straightforward! +1

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose $x\in H\cap K$. Use Lagrange's theorem for $\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: I think Lagrange is overkill.

Comment: Lagrange is the most fundamental theorem in the theory of finite groups. How could this possibly be an overkill?

Comment: I don't think Lagrange is overkill after the first 2-3 hours of group theory studies: in most books it is introduced in the first 1-2 chapters and the OP's comments below other question show she's acquainted with it.

Comment: @Curufin, my apologies --- I was misunderstanding Lagrange's Theorem to be the one about the order of an element dividing the order of the group, whereas I now realize it's the one about the order of a subgroup dividing the order of the group.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not choose any answer yet, here is more "physical" approach. The purpose of writing this is not to have an efficient answer.

If we have a nontrivial $x \in H \cap K$, then $\langle x \rangle$ has order $5$ or $25$ by Lagrange. This contradicts the fact that this cyclic subgroup is contained in $H$.